# Should global buffers be used instead of local buffers?

Tags: java

When copying, commons-io uses a local buffer:

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/io/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/CopyUtils.java?view=markup
(search for DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)

while Eclipse uses a static synchronized buffer that prevents concurrent copy operations:
http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.core.resources/src/org/eclipse/core/internal/utils/FileUtil.java?view=markup
(search for buffer)

It seems like the static buffer may improve performance when coping small files sequentially but will degrade performance in parallel copy.

Does eclipse static synchronized buffer have real world performance improvements or it is just over-engineering?

What do you recommend using in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really makes no significant performance difference, and a static buffer is generally a really bad idea unless you know you are threadsafe. They did it (if you look at the comment) because they understand the synchronization in a higher level object.

So always just allocate a dynamic buffer.

Comment: Apache Commons is more than 10 years old and was written when VMs had been less efficient when allocating memory and when multi-core CPU were far less commen than today.

Comment: @x4u Apache Commons is not using the static buffer. Do you mean that a static buffer is preferred? Could you explain why?

Comment: Yes sorry, I got it wrong. I thought Commons was using the static buffer. I would suggest not to use the static buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the commons-io approach:  easier to read, and performance is probably very similar.

The cost is that commons-io will create a new byte[8192] once per copy() call.  But remember two things:

1. new byte[8192] is almost instantaneous on most systems.  This is not an expensive constructor to call!
2. InputStream.read() is usually very slow in most situations!  (e.g. File reading, or Socket reading!)

And so the call to new byte[8192] will be VERY fast compared to the actual stream copying.  The Eclipse optimization (in this particular example) is a false economy (it's not the bottleneck!) that results in more complicated, harder to understand code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about performance, I would use direct ByteBuffers.  This sort of buffering was the best when it came out but NIO (available since 2004) is faster IMHO. (up to 30%)

Otherwise, the cost of allocation is pretty small (Unless you are trying to avoid GCs)